# How does one comment out a HTML code that has PHP in it?

Tags: php

I have a HTML code that has PHP in it and I wanted to comment it all out.

```
<input type="hidden" name="returnurl" value="<?php if (!empty($link)) {echo $link;}?>">
```

How do I comment out both the HTML and PHP without commenting each separately?

Comment: By writing one comment, probably directly before the line it is intended to explain? Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: Sorry. I meant comment out the code.

Answer (score 8):

Thanks to Ross Patterson, I discover that I completely misunderstood the question. So here is the new answer. I keep the old answer below, since it may still be useful for some people.

### New answer

You case is easy, since there are neither PHP strings, nor comments in your code. This means that commenting this particular piece of code is as simple as:

```
<?php
/*
<input type="hidden" name="returnurl" value="<?php if (!empty($link)) {echo $link;}?>">
*/
?>
```

The problem is that you will sooner or later find yourself in a situation where this doesn't work, because the commented code contains itself comments. Imagine the following piece of code:

```
<div>
  You're logged in.
  <?php
  /**
   * Says "hello" to the person.
   * @param string $name The name of the person.
   */
  function SayHello($name)
  {
    echo 'Hello, ' . $name;
  }

  SayHello($personName);
  ?>
</div>
```

You can't possibly embed this in a single comment, since it will break on line 7.

What you can do, instead, is to use [NOWDOC syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc) to embed the code in a string and never use this string:

```
<?php
$GUID2328f09280b94c22867d831a885b57eb = <<<'GUID2328f09280b94c22867d831a885b57eb'
<div>
  You're logged in.
  <?php
  /**
   * Says "hello" to the person.
   * @param string $name The name of the person.
   */
  function SayHello($name)
  {
    echo 'Hello, ' . $name;
  }

  SayHello($personName);
  ?>
</div>
GUID2328f09280b94c22867d831a885b57eb
?>
```

A few remarks:

- *Why do I use NOWDOC instead of a simple string?*

  A simple string will break on line 5 (on “Says "hello"”). A single-quoted string will break on line 2 (on “You're”).
- *Why do I use NOWDOC instead of HEREDOC?*

  Because I don't want the variable names to be parsed. Parsing variables in such context would cause issues which are very difficult to find and debug, since the scope changes.
- *What is this scary GUID2328…?*

  I use a [GUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier) to be sure that, firstly, the string will never terminate before the actual end, and, secondly, the string variable will never be reasonably used later in the code. I put a GUID prefix since HEREDOC/NOWDOC require the name to start by a letter, not a digit.

  If you find it ugly and stupid, feel free to use whatever syntax you want.
- *It would impact the performance of the web app, right?*

  Don't do premature optimization. Initializing a string can have a performance cost, but either it will be small enough to care, or maybe even PHP interpreter will be smart enough to optimize code and remove the unused string (I highly doubt it).

Note that you're not expected to comment large chunks of code in the first place. If you don't need the code, just remove it. If you think you might be need it later, let version control take care of it (you're using version control, are you?).

---

### Old answer

Who are you commenting for?

- Developers? Then comment in PHP. Example:

  ```
  <?php /** The value is hidden for the moment to be backwards compatible, but the field
          * would be removed in the near future, since having this field presents a
          * security risk. See bug report 1422, http://example.com/bugs/1422 */ ?>
  <input type="hidden" name="returnurl" value="<?php if (!empty($link)) {echo $link;}?>">
  ```

  Remember that HTML comments are displayed publicly. Putting a comment such as in the example above is a gift for a hacker.
- Users? Then comment in HTML. Example:

  ```
  <!-- If `returnurl` is null or empty, the client would be redirected to the home page
       of the website. -->
  <input type="hidden" name="returnurl" value="<?php if (!empty($link)) {echo $link;}?>">
  ```

  Here, the intention is to tell something useful to the users who will for example screen scrap your website or do something which manipulates HTML (the only valid example I would see is that doing a real API is too expensive for you, so you're authorizing and inviting the users to parse HTML code directly).

Remember that:

1. HTML comments can be seen by everyone,
2. HTML comments are sent to the client, increasing the usage of the bandwidth. Note: in most cases, you don't care; it's not a few additional bytes which will affect the performance of your website, unless you're working on Google homepage.

Comment: OP means "how do I disable the code", not "how do I describe the code".  But this is a nice answer to the latter, so +1 anyway.

Comment: @Ross Patterson: thank you for noting my mistake; I should have read the question more carefully. I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: +1 foe the idea but would a lot of NOWDOC strings add over head to the parser?

Comment: @tgkprog: I already answered it. Look for "It would impact the performance of the web app, right?" in the answer.

Comment: thought that was about the runtime after parsing. but i guess they nearly the same a few cycles to pay for but a quick way to do it. would it work if you had a NOWDOC string in the code commenting out?

Comment: This is up there as one of my favourite answers on stackoverflow, but I think something should be pointed out... The closing PHP tag `?>` automatically implies a semicolon, but if you want to have working code after the Nowdoc statement and before the end of the PHP block, then you will need to add a semicolon to terminate the Nowdoc statement.

Answer (score 2):

As your example is written you can't comment both out without commenting them separately.

You can do it all at once if you make PHP print the html as well as the values. Such as:

```
<?php 
     print '<input type="hidden" name="returnurl" value="';
     if (!empty($link)) {echo $link;}
     print '">';
?>
```

Of course there are better ways to write this of course, but now you can just do this:

```
<?php /*
     print '<input type="hidden" name="returnurl" value="';
     if (!empty($link)) {echo $link;}
     print '">';
     */
?>
```

PHP is processed into HTML and then sent to the client requesting the page. That client then processes the HTML. So PHP comments are only seen by the PHP processor and the HTML comments are not touched by the PHP processor, but the browser (client) will recognize the HTML comments are skip over them accordingly.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you're commenting blocks of php with little or no HTML, use php comments,  if you're commenting large blocks of HTML with little smatterings of PHP, use HTML comments.

Put the comment wherever and in whatever form is most clear and descriptive, and try to keep a consistent style throughout your coding.

You also should probably differentiate based on what you're actually commenting.  If you're making comments on the HTML structure, use HTML if you're commenting on the details of the php, unless its a one liner in the middle of an HTML block, use php.  The comment style should complement the code style.

Comment: This ofc only if the PHP code that still gets run, but is commented out by html, does not modify stuff.

Comment: @ThomWiggers Not suggesting commenting out php code thats running.  We're talking annotation comments here, not running code.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
<?php /*
<input type="hidden" name="returnurl" value="<?php if (!empty($link)) {echo $link;}?>">
*/ ?>
```

I don't mess much with PHP, but I think that that will work, unless there's already a `*/` in it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- <input type="hidden" name="returnurl" value="<?php //if (!empty($link)) {echo $link;}?>"> -->
```

Just like that

Comment: This doesn't answer the question as it uses both HTML and PHP comments to disable input control.

Answer (score 0):

If you can do some rewriting before commenting (I guess you do not want to just remove the code).

1. Make the code all php,
2. convert any multiline code to a bunch of single line comments
3. finally use a php multi line comment to comment out the whole block

Say you start out with

```
<input type="hidden" name="returnurl" value="<?php 
/**
a multi line
comment here
*/
if (!empty($link)) {echo $link;}?>">
```

Convert it like this

```
<?php 
echo :<input type="hidden" name="returnurl" value="";
//a multi line
//comment here
//
if (!empty($link)) {echo $link;}
echo ">";
?>
```

Finally comment it all out

```
<?php 
/*
echo :<input type="hidden" name="returnurl" value="";
//a multi line
//comment here
//
if (!empty($link)) {echo $link;}
echo ">";*/
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

A very simple approach to de-activate code (temporarily) is to inclose it with

```
<?php if(0) : ?>
...
<?php endif; ?>
```

This is independent from any comment style inside the block. The coding style violation `if(0)` istead of `if (0)` is intended, because it makes it easier to find those locations lateron.

Answer (score 0):

**nibra** is the only one to understand this question and give a valuable answer.

```
<?php if(0) : ?>
...
<?php endif; ?>
```

This is the easiest method I have discovered to comment out a block of HTML code that contains PHP without having to go into the block and fiddle with its content.